# How can I read "Line Numbers" when convert docx word file to text?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, docx

I converted .docx word file (xml content) to text with this code (in C#):

```
private string ReadNode(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node == null || node.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
        return string.Empty;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (child.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;
        switch (child.LocalName)
        {
            case "t":                           // Text
                sb.Append(child.InnerText.TrimEnd());

                string space = ((XmlElement)child).GetAttribute("xml:space");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(space) && space == "preserve")
                    sb.Append(' ');
                break;

            case "tab":// Tab
                sb.Append("\t");
                break;
            case "p":// Paragraph
                if (ReadNode(child).Trim() != "")
                {
                    sb.Append(ReadNode(child));
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);                            
                }
                break;
            default:
                sb.Append(ReadNode(child));
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

How can I read "Line Numbers" of page content in my code(similar read "p" or "tab")?

Please see the image file(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVx3O.jpg) :
[image: LineNumbers in docx file.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I'm afraid that the XML doesn't store that information.  The XML simply stores the general layout of the text, so you would have to try to replicate the layout and then see where each piece of text would fall.  That's not very easy.  Explain your problem (why you are trying to do this) in further detail, perhaps we can come up with another solution which doesn't require getting the line numbers?

The information you need is under one of the other "xmlData" nodes

```
See "<Pages>2</Pages>"
```

Full xml below:

```
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/docProps/app.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml" pkg:padding="256">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties" xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
        <Template>Normal.dotm</Template>
        <TotalTime>0</TotalTime>
        <Pages>2</Pages>
        <Words>341</Words>
        <Characters>1948</Characters>
        <Application>Microsoft Office Word</Application>
        <DocSecurity>0</DocSecurity>
        <Lines>16</Lines>
        <Paragraphs>4</Paragraphs>
        <ScaleCrop>false</ScaleCrop>
        <HeadingPairs>
          <vt:vector size="2" baseType="variant">
            <vt:variant>
              <vt:lpstr>Title</vt:lpstr>
            </vt:variant>
            <vt:variant>
              <vt:i4>1</vt:i4>
            </vt:variant>
          </vt:vector>
        </HeadingPairs>
        <TitlesOfParts>
          <vt:vector size="1" baseType="lpstr">
            <vt:lpstr/>
          </vt:vector>
        </TitlesOfParts>
        <Company/>
        <LinksUpToDate>false</LinksUpToDate>
        <CharactersWithSpaces>2285</CharactersWithSpaces>
        <SharedDoc>false</SharedDoc>
        <HyperlinksChanged>false</HyperlinksChanged>
        <AppVersion>14.0000</AppVersion>
      </Properties>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
```

Comment: Thank's from you, but I can read line numbers for each line no total line numbers or page numbers. Please see the image file that added to question. I active line numbers from layout from page setup toolbar in office word. I want split line text by this numbers. a few of these lines no have any new line charachter ! Please help me!